# How can I replace colon with dot in caption figure?

Tags: floats, captions

I have a `\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}`

I have something like this: `Figure: xxxxxxxx`

And I need: `Figure. xxxxxxxxx`

I need change the colon with a dot.

An example of my figures:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{ZonaInfluencia.png}
  \caption{Study area}
  \label{AreaInfluencia}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: have a look at the `caption` package

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}`